# Energy and momentum conservation in ARPES

Tags: solid-state-physics, spectroscopy, photoelectric-effect, photon-emission

In  [ARPES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle-resolved_photoemission_spectroscopy) experiment we assume that electron's momentum in-plane component is conserved, while perpendicular component - NOT.

This means what total momentum of electron |**K**| changes, which means that the Energy of electron should change as well.

On the other hand, we assume that the energy of photo-emitted electrons is conserved.

Then, how can we explain change in momentum, without having a change in Energy?

Comment: There is the work function barrier.

Comment: This is exactly that I was thinkigin:
can we say that work function is proporctional to change in Kz?